# Why does my 5.5 nap so little during the day?

Tags: sleep, feeding, naps

She used to do 3 naps during the day, for a total of 4 hrs.

Now, her total nap time during the day on average is 1-2 hours per day.

She sleeps great at night, for 8-10 straight hours with only 1 to 2 wakings, and no night feeding.

She also feeds a total of 20 oz per 24 hours, no solids.

She exhibits no sign of distress, no loud crying, laughs and plays well.

Is this normal?

Comment: It might be helpful to use the word "month" somewhere in your discription

Comment: Normal is a tough word when it comes to babies. If it works for her ...

Comment: Different people just have different sleep requirements and she sounds like she is doing fine. But if she or the caregiver gets tired during the day, my suggestion is to convert nap time to "quiet time" for everyone's sanity. As they get older, quiet time will become homework/ hobby time.

Comment: @Stone - How do you explain (or enforce) quiet time to a 5.5 month old? Parents around the world would pay good money for this ability. :)

Comment: @anongoodnurse, apologies, I thought it was a 5.5 year old! But quiet time to me just means quiet activities. Younger children obviously need supervision and some interaction. At 5.5 month this can be going for long quiet walks in a carrier, looking at photographs, board books and interesting objects (aquariums, wind catchers etc) with someone else, or just the baby watching an older child at HIS quiet time (painting, building etc). Perhaps I was also lucky that my then- preschooler was careful and then 5.5 month old was very interested in the world around him.

Answer (score 1):

At birth, baby sleep patterns aren’t the natural cycle of day and night. It can take several months before babies become fully adapted to the 24-hour day. (as your baby is 5.5 month old, so this is all normal)

see [This](http://www.parentingscience.com/baby-sleep-patterns.html) for everything about baby's sleep.